# Best way to arrange a HairDresser database based in their skills

Tags: database, sqlite

I need some help in a smart way to organize a database for a hairdresser shop.

So far, I understand that I need a table for the hairdressers containing usual data such as id, name, etc.

I also think I need a table for the procedures the hairdressers can perform. This table would contain the procedure id, description, time required, cost, price and so on.

But I don't see a good way to link those two tables. For example: Professional A can do procedures #1 and #3, but not #2.

How to include this info in the database?

I thought of two possible ways:

1. Make the procedures be columns in the Professionals table, and assign true in the column in case a professional can perform that procedure;
2. Make the professionals be columns in the Procedures table, assigning true if the procedure can be performed by that professional.

Neither possibilities seem to be quite the best way to achieve what I want, specially if the number of professionals/procedures get large.

Since I have very few experience in this, I count on your help giving me some insights in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can have a separate new table to handle and map this information. Let's say you have created a table `professional_procedures`, then you can store the *professionalID* and the corresponding *procedureID* in it. Basically having a third table that references both the original tables.

This is a m:n relation and it will be good to have a separate table that contains foreign keys to both the other tables.

Professional (Hairdresser) <===> Professional_Procedures <===> Procedures

```
CREATE TABLE Professional_Procedures (
    ProfessionalID int not null,
    ProcedureID int not null,
    constraint PK_PersonRoles PRIMARY KEY (ProfessionalID ,ProcedureID ),
    constraint FK_PersonRoles_Persons FOREIGN KEY (ProfessionalID ) references Professional(ID),
    constraint FK_PersonRoles_Roles FOREIGN KEY (ProcedureID ) references Procedures(ID)
)
```

This should get you the complete mapping of procedure details for a particular professional.

So to explain this, let's say **Professional_Procedures** table has below data:

```
ProfessionID ProcedureID
     1           P1
     2           P3
     1           P4
```

This means, Professional (with ID 1) can perform Procedures P1 and P4 however profession (with ID 2) can perform procedure P3 only.

Hope I got your query right.

Comment: Looks like you got exactly what I need. I will try this and then come back with the results. If this solves my problem I accept your answer. Thank you .